# I have problem in keras , I have deleted some .py files

Tags: python, keras, dataset, jupyter-lab

I deleted some .py files and some fashion_mnist dataset from several path locations because I had problem in downloading fashion_mnist dataset
now there is some .py missing files
I got this error:

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\jupyterlab-debugger\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py, in run_code:
Line 3441:  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

In  [5]:
Line 3:     from tensorflow import keras

File C:\Users\legion\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\keras_*init*_.py, in :
Line 19:    from . import datasets

File C:\Users\legion\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\datasets_*init*_.py, in :
Line 13:    from . import fashion_mnist

### ImportError: cannot import name 'fashion_mnist' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.keras.datasets' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\legion\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\datasets_*init*_.py)

how to solve this problem?
I tried this in the environment that I am using

```
pip update --all

pip install keras
```

but the error is still there

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6hVd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the data set yourself. If the data set is not found in the path below, the problem will be solved if you download and add it manually.

```
 C:\Users\Username.keras\datasets
```

or

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets
```

[Keras Mnist Datasets](https://keras.io/api/datasets/)

Comment: I don't have keras in the first path or  have tensorflow in the second path so is there anyway to uninstall keras or tensorflow and install them , and will it work?

Comment: Yes it will probably work. My advice is to create a virtual environment and work in that virtual environment. This way, a corrupted library will not affect other environments and the actual python path. You can try uninstalling all keras and tensorflow libraries and reinstalling them.

Comment: You should accept the answer for others if it works. @mero